# Need help vectorizing a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I'm trying to speed up an R function from a package I regularly use, so any help vectorizing the for-loop below would be much appreciated!

```
y <- array(0, dim=c(75, 12))
samp <- function(x) x<-sample(c(0,1), 1)
y <- apply(y, c(1,2), samp)

nr <- nrow(y)
nc <- ncol(y)
rs <- rowSums(y)
p <- colSums(y)
out <- matrix(0, nrow = nr, ncol = nc)

for (i in 1:nr) {
  out[i, sample.int(nc, rs[i], prob = p)] <- 1
}
```

The issue I'm having a hard time getting around is the reference to object 'rs' within the loop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is an [RcppArmadillo implementation of `sample`](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-the-Rcpp-based-sample-implementation/). So, you could try implementing this with Rcpp and see if it's much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options:

This one uses the somewhat discouraged `<<-` operator:

```
lapply(1:nr, function(i) out[i, sample.int(nc, rs[i], prob = p)] <<- 1)
```

This one uses more traditional indexing:

```
out[do.call('rbind',sapply(1:nr, function(i) cbind(i,sample.int(nc, rs[i], prob = p))))] <- 1
```

I suppose you could also use `Vectorize` to do an implicit `mapply` on your function:

```
z <- Vectorize(sample.int, vectorize.args='size')(nc, rs, prob=p)
out[cbind(rep(1:length(z), sapply(z, length)), unlist(z))] <- 1
```

But I don't think that's necessarily any cleaner.

And, indeed, @Roland is correct, that all of these are slower than just doing the `for` loop:

```
> microbenchmark(op(), t1(), t2(), t3())
Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 op() 494.970 513.8290 521.7195 532.3040 1902.898   100
 t1() 591.962 602.1615 609.4745 617.5570 2369.385   100
 t2() 734.756 754.7700 764.3925 782.4825 2205.421   100
 t3() 642.383 672.9815 711.4700 763.8150 2283.169   100
```

Yay for benefit-free obfuscation!

Comment: Using `lapply` and `<<-` to replace `for` should be more than *somewhat* discouraged.

Comment: I don't think any of your suggestions is faster than the original `for` loop. They are only more obfuscated.

Comment: @Roland I would agree with that.